# Unable to create Dynamic from GADT Expression Type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamic, gadt

I have the following in Haskell (as a minimum example).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Data.Dynamic    

data Expr a where
  Lift  :: (Show a) => a -> Expr a --Lift some type into Expr
  Lam   :: (Expr a -> Expr b) -> Expr (a -> b)
  Const :: Expr a -> Expr b -> Expr a
```

When I try to create a Dynamic from the following, I get an error that I'm unsure how to correct.

```
--This is the code
toDyn $ (Lam (Const (Lift 1)))
-- This is the error
-- • No instance for (Typeable b0) arising from a use of ‘toDyn’
-- • In the expression: toDyn (Lam (Const (Lift 1)))
--   In an equation for ‘it’: it = toDyn (Lam (Const (Lift 1)))
```

Is there there any way around this? The other constructors all work fine (my actual program has over 100 others!) but Const is really giving me trouble!

Comment: I guess you need to provide a specific type to that `(Lam ...)`, otherwise it is too general and can only be given a polymorphic type. Basically, you have to choose what `b` is in the `Const` application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that type of the second argument to `Const`, the one that is being thrown away, needs to be `Typeable`. But it's a fully general type variable, without a Typeable constraint. If you write something like

```
toDyn (Const (Lift 1) :: Expr Int -> Expr Int)
```

or

```
toDyn (Lam (Const (Lift 1) :: Expr Int -> Expr Int))
```

both work.

Comment: Is there a way I can give the general variable a typeable constraint?
I've tried `data Expr a where Const :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Expr a -> Expr b -> Expr a` without much luck. I've even tried autoderiving Typeable for Expr.

Comment: @Donovan I was just playing with that, but I don't think `Typeable` works like that - I think the problem is that the type variable is existential.

Comment: @Donovan in the end, there needs to be a specific type for the `Typeable` instance. But because of the existential, it can never be provided. At least I think that's what's happening. You get similar errors if you try `toDyn` directly on a polymorphic function like `toDyn (\a -> a)`. Whereas `toDyn (\a -> a + a)` is ok, because of defaulting of the `Num` constraint.

Comment: Thanks for this, maybe I can try something fancy using type families to extract the correct type from a custom Dynamic-like structure.